# Impala Month Name Function

Tags: sql, impala, sql-date-functions

Can we convert month numbers to month name. 
I can see a function called month name

https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_datetime_functions.html#datetime_functions__month

But it is not working .

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: select distinct(date_column),month(date_column),monthname(date_column) from  
tablename;

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to a unix timestamp and use:

```
from_unixtime(col, 'MMM')
```

Comment: I am looking for full monthname.

Comment: @NambiRajan . . . You can try `'MMMM'`.  Impala has pretty poor documentation on this function.

Comment: It works with from_timestamp function in hive but not in impala.

Comment: @NambiRajan . . . You may need to use a `case` expression or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `decode` for brevity. A slightly more verbose solution can be expressed using a `case` expression.

```
select decode(month(a.date_processed), 1, "Jan", 2, "Feb", 3, "Mar".....) as month_name
from your_table;
```

Comment: already using a case statement only. 
CASE
WHEN CAST(MONTH(a.DATE_PROCESSED) AS INT) = 1 THEN 'January'
WHEN CAST(MONTH(a.DATE_PROCESSED) AS INT) = 2 THEN 'February'
WHEN CAST(MONTH(a.DATE_PROCESSED) AS INT) = 3 THEN 'March'
WHEN CAST(MONTH(a.DATE_PROCESSED) AS INT) = 4 THEN 'April'
WHEN CAST(MONTH(a.DATE_PROCESSED) AS INT) = 5 THEN 'May'
WHEN CAST(MONTH(a.DATE_PROCESSED) AS INT) = 6 THEN 'June'
ELSE 'other' END AS 'Month',

Comment: @NambiRajan Are you getting an error when using monthname function? If so what's the error?

Comment: User XXXXXXXXXX does not have privileges to access: default

Comment: @NambiRajan Does that error not occur when running your query with case statements? It will make your life easier if you ask an impala super user at work to grant you appropriate access.

Comment: Yes month function works fine in the case statement.I have issues only with the monthname function. if it is an access issue month function in case statement also should fail with access error right?

Comment: I would think so too. Maybe check with a super user to see if he/she is able to run the query with monthname.